# How to Use Google Sheets' Macro to Copy Data from Volatile (randbetween) Cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-macro

What I would like to be able to do is execute a macro that copies the data from a cell with a *randbetween* formula, and pastes that data (copy/paste values only) into another cell. When I attempt this manually, it works just fine. However, when I tell the macro to do it, the value that is copied/pasted is not the correct value.

[image]

So in others, using the image above as reference: I want the be able to execute a macro to copy the value 15 from A1 into B1 w/o it changing. However, every macro that I've attempted changes the value on its way to B1.

I'm hoping what I'm asking is a simple fix. I don't mean to ask anybody to write a complex code.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] AFAIK there is no simple fix for this.

Comment: Same question on [so]: [Google Sheets Macro won't copy/paste correct randomly generated value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58927831/1595451)